# What is the meaning of 'now' in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

> She (Helen Keller) now understood what words were.

I'd like to know the meaning of 'now' in the sentence.

Comment: How about adding [**a little more context**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)? Did you look up the word [*now*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=now) in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Helen Keller was born blind and deaf, so she did not learn to speak or read in the usual way. She was eight years old when a newly appointed governess tried to communicate with her by tracing letters with her finger on Helen's hand.

> Until that time, she was unable to communicate, but **now** understood what words were.

In this context, the word **now** has this meaning: "1.5 (in a narrative or account of past events) at the time spoken of or referred to."- [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/now)

Answer (score 1):

The word **now** used in the past context,(in a narrative or account of past events) means **at the time spoken of** or referred to.

> She was nineteen now, and she was alone.